# I have a CD to upgrade to windows 8.1. Is it safe?

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows, windows-8

I brought a CD to upgrade my windows 7 to 8.1 pro, I use windows 7 alongside ubuntu on my PC. So if I proceed with the upgrade will the GRUB get damaged or only the windows 7 erases and 8.1 gets installed?

Comment: You can try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) - try and have a go at Windows 8(.1) before going anywhere near installing it...

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, installing Windows 8.1 from Windows 7 will indeed overwrite your MBR, but upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1 should not.

However if your MBR does get overwritten, it is still possible to repair it.
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @bharat Just be sure to make a backup of the data in both systems before you have a go at this.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, upgrading windows should not affect Ubuntu at all. Make a backup of your files and make sure that you follow the prompts carefully coz sometimes Windows tends to see Linux files as trash and can prompt you to delete them.